# How to get selected value of multiple-selection listbox (InfoPath)

Tags: listbox, infopath, multipleselection

How to get the selected value from the multiple-selection `listbox` ( `InfoPath form`)

I have a multiple selection `listbox` like this:

```
Display text , Value
110-SS , 110
120-ST , 120
130-SW , 130
```

how can I make the condition when `listbox` selected value was contain with `'130'` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a condition that is true when the MSLB has 130 selected, you would simply use:

***ListBoxField*** equals 130

If you want a condition that is true when the MSLB does not have 130 selected, you would use:

All instances of ***ListBoxField*** are not equal to 130